# Nginx - branch on parameter in location context

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use the HttpEchoModule to sleep for a random amount of time when i hit a location with a specific parameter:

```
location = /api/shouldSend {
      if ($arg_blah = "test") {
        set_random $res 0 25;
        echo_sleep $res;
      }


      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      echo_location /some_other_location;
}
```

If the 'if' is removed, sleeping and moving to a new location works as expected, but I really need to check the parameter here. After figuring out that this didn't work I came across this article: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil.

None of the workarounds seem appropriate. Is there anything else i can do here?

Thanks!

Comment: And which version of the module are you using?

Comment: nginx version 1.6.2, echo version 0.56, set misc version 0.26